# which is the best way to read data from a table in a pdf?

Tags: java, pdf, export

I want to read the data from the table in this PDF.

[PDF](https://www.fnbaloncesto.com/img/noticias/103/pdfs/ENaB%2020180317.pdf)

I had thought about reading the PDF, exporting it to an Excel and then use the data. The problem of reading the pdf and exporting it to Excel is that there are elements of columns that move to empty columns because I read with Apache Poi, and in this way the whole PDF is saved in a string.

Another way was to read exact coordinates data, but I do not think it's a very good option.

Could someone advise me? Which way is better or some new way?

Comment: Best way to read a PDF is to use a PDF library. Now you go do some **research** to see if you can find one that allows reading PDF table content from Java.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the best luck using Xpdf pdftotext with a combination of the -layout and -table options.

[Xpdf Link](https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html)

You would call like this:

```
pdftotext -table c:\temp\ENaB20180317.pdf c:\temp\output.txt
```

You could then parse by getting the starting column position from the header on each page.

Antoher good option is [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) it may extract the text in a format you can use without having to call a separate command line app.

Answer (score 0):

Your example file is tagged. As long as the PDFs you are interested in are appropriately tagged, you can use a tool that can extract the tagging information, e.g. with iText 7 you can do

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource);
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader);

TaggedPdfReaderTool tool = new TaggedPdfReaderTool(document);
try (   OutputStream result = new FileOutputStream("ENaB 20180317.txt")   ) {
    tool.convertToXml(result);
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
<Workbook>
<Worksheet>
<Table bBox="[-12.1039 12.0189 829.816 607.339 ]" o="/Layout">
<TR>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.600006 0.800003 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
FECHA</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.600006 0.800003 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
HORA</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.600006 0.800003 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
CATEGOR&#205;A</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.600006 0.800003 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
PARTIDO</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.600006 0.800003 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
PABELL&#211;N</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.600006 0.800003 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
LOCALIDAD</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.600006 0.800003 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
ARBITRO
PRINCIPAL</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.600006 0.800003 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
ARBITRO
AUXILIAR</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.600006 0.800003 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
ACTA</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.600006 0.800003 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
CRONO</TD>
<TD>
FECHA</TD>
<TD>
HORA</TD>
<TD>
CATEGOR&#205;A</TD>
<TD>
PARTIDO</TD>
<TD>
PABELL&#211;N</TD>
<TD>
LOCALIDAD</TD>
<TD>
ARBITRO
PRINCIPAL</TD>
<TD>
ARBITRO
AUXILIAR</TD>
<TD>
ACTA</TD>
<TD>
CRONO</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
16/03/2018</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
17:30</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
MINI. FEM. GR.B</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
EG&#220;ES-MENDILLORRI 2006*  -  ARDOI ABEJAS</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
P. TRINKETE</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
PAMPLONA</TD>
<TD>
</TD>
<TD>
</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
I.VELASCO</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
16/03/2018</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
17:30</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
PREMINI. MAS. GR.1-10</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
SAN IGNACIO 07  -  CB BURLADA</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
P. SAN IGNACIO</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
PAMPLONA</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
A.ELOUARDI</TD>
<TD>
</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
A.IRAOLA</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
17/03/2018</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
09:10</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
INFANTIL MAS. 1&#170;</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
GAZTE BERRIAK  -  LAGUNAK</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
P. ARROSADIA P.I</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
PAMPLONA</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
P.HORME&#209;O</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
M.YKHELEF</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
I.VELASCO</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
17/03/2018</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
09:10</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
INFANTIL MAS. 1&#170;</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
SAN CERNIN B  -  AUTOBUSES LA PAMPLONESA ARDOI</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
P. ARROSADIA P.II</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
PAMPLONA</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
J.HUEGUN</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
A.PIDAL</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
M.TESO</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
OFI.CNaB</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
17/03/2018</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
09:10</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
MINI. MAS. GR.B</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
PATXI LARRAINZAR  LARANJA*  -  LA COMPASION*</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
P. AZPILAGA&#209;A P.III</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
PAMPLONA</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
S.VELIZAROVA</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
N.VILLAR</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
L.ORTIZ</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
OFI.CNaB</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
17/03/2018</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
09:10</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
MINI. MAS. GR.A</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
NAVARRO VILLOSLADA 06M  -  ADEMAR</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
P. IRIBARREN P.II</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
PAMPLONA</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
A.ELOUARDI</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
R.MARTIN</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
A.DE LA NAVA</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
OFI.CNaB</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
17/03/2018</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
09:10</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
CADETE MAS. 2&#170;</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
MENDIEG&#220;ES BNC*  -  BERRIOZAR MKE</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
P. LARRABIDE P.I</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
PAMPLONA</TD>
<TD>
</TD>
<TD>
</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
I.LECUMBERRI</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
J.RAMIREZ</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
17/03/2018</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
09:15</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
PREINF. FEM. 1&#170;</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
MENDILLORRI 2005 AMARILLO  -  CBASK M</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
P. AZPILAGA&#209;A P.I</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
PAMPLONA</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
A.PEREZGARCIA</TD>
<TD>
</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[1.0 1.0 1.0 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
A.IRIGOIEN</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
17/03/2018</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
09:15</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
INFANTIL MAS. 2&#170;</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
CANTOLAGUA  -  CB ONCINEDA SK*</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
P. AZPILAGA&#209;A P.II</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
PAMPLONA</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" o="/Layout">
P.ALVAREZ</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
R.GARCIAMIGUEL</TD>
<TD backgroundColor="[0.752945 0.752945 0.752945 ]" blockAlign="/Middle" borderColor="[0.0 0.0 0.0 ]" borderStyle="/Solid" borderThickness="1.0" o="/Layout">
I.TAGUA</TD>
</TR>
[...]
</Table>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```